# Debian 12 Wireguard VPN not working/too slow

Tags: debian, ubuntu, vpn, wireguard

I installed Wireguard on Ubuntu 22 server via this [script](https://github.com/angristan/wireguard-install). After the installation I scanned QR code from my Android phone and tried it - VPN worked perfectly fine. Then I created a different user for my PC (with Windows 10), downloaded the `wg0-client-pc.conf` file from server to my computer, imported the file using the official Wireguard app for Windows and, again, it worked absolutely fine!

Then I created new client for my second PC with almost clean installed Debian 12 (have been using it for only 2 days) and did this:

1. Installed `wireguard` and `openresolv` packages.
2. Downloaded the `wg0-client-pc2.conf` file on Debian, renamed it to `wg0.conf` and moved it to `/etc/wireguard`
3. Then tried `sudo wg-quick up wg0` and got seemingly fine output.

But then I tried checking my IP using google (browser - Firefox ESR) and it would load too slow, almost seemed like it wouldn't load at all. I tried clicking first 3 links - all of them were loading indefinitely. Very rarely some websites actually load.

Stopped the Wireguard using `sudo wg-quick down wg0` and tried checking IP again - everything was OK, websites would load normally.

I thought this may be an issue with Firefox ESR so I installed speedtest-cli and measured my normal speeds using `speedtest-cli --simple`:

- Ping: ~14ms
- Download: ~15 Mbit/s
- Upload: ~11 Mbit/s

Did the same after `sudo wg-quick up wg0`:

- Ping: ~237ms
- Download: 0.66 Mbit/s
- Upload: 0.20 Mbit/s

What could be the problem? Wireguard VPN works fine on my other devices, but not on Debian.

Answer (score 2):

Searched for similar problems and [found](https://gist.github.com/nitred/f16850ca48c48c79bf422e90ee5b9d95) that the problem was with the MTU. On my Debian 12 PC I got the default 1500 MTU for `wg0` interface, but on the server it was 1420 which caused some problems. After some experiments the optimal peer MTU range was found - ~1300. With this number I am getting consistently ~70% of my normal Internet speed (up and down).

Comment: How did you find the optimal peer MTU range? As far as I know Wireguard should automatically discover that and it should be set to 1500 MTU by default.